Checking if squaring a square matrix preserves equal row and column sums
I am studying the properties of square matrices and am particularly interested in understanding whether a specific property is maintained after squaring the matrix. Specifically, I want to know if a square matrix $A$ with equal row and column sums retains this property when squared, resulting in $A^2$.
Here’s the problem statement:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with the property that the sum of the elements in each row is equal to a constant $S$, and the sum of the elements in each column is also equal to $S$.

Compute the square of this matrix, $A^2 = A \cdot A$.

Investigate whether the sums of the rows and columns of $A^2$ remain equal to each other (though not necessarily equal to $S$).


As a specific example, consider the following $4 \times 4$ matrix $F$:
$$F = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
4 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
For this matrix $F$, the sum of each row and each column is equal to 10:

Row sums: $1 + 3 + 2 + 4 = 10$, $4 + 2 + 3 + 1 = 10$, $2 + 4 + 1 + 3 = 10$, $3 + 1 + 4 + 2 = 10$
Column sums: $1 + 4 + 2 + 3 = 10$, $3 + 2 + 4 + 1 = 10$, $2 + 3 + 1 + 4 = 10$, $4 + 1 + 3 + 2 = 10$

After squaring the matrix $F$:
$$F^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
29 & 21 & 29 & 21 \\
21 & 29 & 21 & 29 \\
29 & 21 & 29 & 21 \\
21 & 29 & 21 & 29 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
You can clearly see that the sum of each row and each column is equal to $10^2=100$
This example shows that the property of equal row and column sums is maintained after squaring in this specific case.
I would like to understand:

If there is a general proof or counterexample that demonstrates whether this property is preserved or not for any $n \times n$ matrix with equal row and column sums.

If the property is not preserved, what conditions or specific types of matrices might retain the equal row and column sums after squaring?

It seems that the sum of each column and each row of the $F^2$ matrix is the square of the sum for matrix $F$. Is this a general case?


Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

This formulation includes a clear example of a matrix satisfying the initial conditions, making the problem statement more comprehensive for the Math Stack Exchange community.

Does this answer your question? Product of doubly stochastic matrix. Don't get distracted by the specific conditions in the definition of doubly stochastic matrix. The computation in the proof is what is the same.

$Ae = \lambda e\implies A^2 e = \lambda Ae = \lambda^2 e$

Thanks, I've figure it out that the properties will remain the same.

And as you can see from the proof, the property holds for products in general, not only squares. Moreover, all is needed is that for one matrix in the product all rows have the same sum and for the other matrix all columns. Both matrices do not need to have both rows and columns having the same sum.
